# javax persistence *switch* to flat file

Tags: java, jdbc, persistence, flat-file

I'm writing a Java EE program that manages client data. The original specification was for it to talk to a hosted database that the client would setup, but now (just before deadline) they're saying they can't get that together and want it to talk to local files instead. (The program will be used in contexts where internet access is infeasible. Also, the user will want to email or dropbox the files around and expresses some hostility to the idea of my starting a mysql server on their local machine.)

The persistence layer is implemented with `javax.persistence`, configured to talk to a mysql database. What I'd love is to keep the program as similar as possible and switch to configuring my `EntityManagerFactory` to talk to a flat file if it can't connect to mysql. Is there a jdbc driver that will talk to a flat file?

(Searching on this subject turns up a number of options, but none of them look obviously supported/tested/likely to be robust. If there's a standard solution, it's the one I'm looking for.)

Comment: IMO, you're in big trouble. I don't know of any already implemented JDBC driver that communicates with flat files. One possible solution would be to use an embedded database (like H2) and have a separate job that extracts info from this database into flat files.

Comment: is the flat file a fixed length record, you could take a look at org.jsefa.flr.annotation.FlrDataType if so

Comment: Just want to note that I wound up going the route of setting up an h2 database and doing mass selects/inserts from lines of CSVs at the start and end of the program. It's good enough for this purpose.